# AWS Elastic Beanstalk with docker-compose.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to deploy several services using `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` with `Docker running on Amazon Linux 2` platform.
Since, there are two services in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  beanstalk-flask:
    image: "anotheruserdocker/beanstalk-flask"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  tasks:
    image: "xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxx:xxx"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I need to change `nginx` service configuration in order to proxy traffic to specific service.
I was following the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html), in which it was noted that you can override the default `nginx.conf` with your own and in order to do it, you need to place your config file in the `application source bundle`, like so `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.
I have also included this `include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;` line in order to override it.
**nginx.conf** file:

```
# Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile    32633;
include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;

upstream service_1 {
    server 172.17.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 256;
}

upstream serivce_2 {
    server 172.17.0.1:5000;
    keepalive 256;
}

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;


    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include  conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
            default       "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass            http://service_1;
            proxy_http_version    1.1;

            proxy_set_header    Connection             $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade                $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Host                   $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass            http://service_2;
            proxy_http_version    1.1;
        }

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }
}
```

Once I'm uploading the application `source bundle` that looks like this:

```
docker-compose.yml
.platform/nginx/nginx.conf
```

the configuration doesn't change.
Am I missing something, is it a bug, or are there any other ways to change/modify the default `nginx` configuration?
Also, I have noticed that upon booting `nginx.service` isn't in running state, is it possible to start this service upon boot?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible solution.

During the creation of `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` environment (if you are using Load Balanced deployment type), you can add processes which Load Balancer will register(?).

Once I've added the processes (that run on `8080` and `5000` ports), I created additional `listener` for the Application Load Balancer that listens to traffic on port `5000` (I only did this for this port, because by default `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` environment creates a listener that forwards traffic to the target group of EC2 instance that was running on the specified `8080` port) and forwards it to the target group of the process that runs it on this port.

> After doing these steps it worked.

Interestingly enough, I don't really know how this worked, I've connected to the EC2 instance and noticed that `nginx.service` was in `inactive` state.

Probably I don't understand clearly how this works behind the scenes, any clarifications would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

P.S.: Once I get enough reputation points, I'll attach some screenshots of the steps taken.

Answer (score 1):

The Nginx service is not configured at all. With AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Docker running on Amazon Linux 2 + docker compose they assume you run Nginx in a container.

It's documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-software-config